# Config cache in laravel 5 results in view not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm tying to render a simple view:

```
public function test()
{
    return \View::make('test');
}
```

I cache my config :

```
$ php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
Configuration cached successfully!
```

When I run it in a web browser I've got :

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
View [test] not found.
in FileViewFinder.php line 140
at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('test', array('/XXXXXX/resources/views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 77
at FileViewFinder->find('test') in Factory.php line 145
at Factory->make('test') in Facade.php line 213
... (framework backtrace)
```

I clear config cache...

```
$ php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!
```

...View is rendered (it's a simple HTML view `resources/views/test.blade.php`)

Why does it only work without cache config ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It does not work when your machine is running on vagrant (or another virtual environnement) and you run `php artisan config:cache` out of vagrant. Do you need to run this command in vagrant. The problem is about path routes (path are not the same in vagrant and out of vagrant).

Comment: same problem can you tell me how to solve this problem ??? i have a defult Homestead not insight project

Comment: The same thing is with Docker. If there is a project in directory outside of container in shared location `php artisan config:cache` has to be run from within container.

Comment: If anyone's having this problem when using Vagrant just do `vagrant ssh`, go to wherever you project is e.g. `cd /var/www/mysite` and then try `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: had this same problem, no vagrant involved, odd

Comment: Why is it using absolute paths? Relative paths would not f*ck everything up in a virtual env. Especially if the framework comes with a virtual environment.