# Laravel: Ran artisan commands and now can't connect

Tags: laravel

I am working on the frontend for a friend's Laravel app and some of the Blade views got cached.  After I ran the following code, I can't even connect to the localhost:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

The site is running on Docker containers, so I even tried to restart them but still nothing but it comes up with a PHP error screen that says:

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [errors.no-store] not found.
```

So is it because I cleared the views?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work when your machine is running on vagrant (or another virtual environment like `docker`) and you run `php artisan config:cache` out of vagrant. Do you need to run this command in vagrant? The problem is about path routes (path are not the same in vagrant and out of vagrant).

The same thing is with Docker. If there is a project in directory outside of container in shared location php artisan config:cache has to be run from within container.

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676605/config-cache-in-laravel-5-results-in-view-not-found).